# unable to render .html via spring security while .jsp works fine

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

Issue:

I have a simple HTML login page that a `userID`, `Password` fields and that is written in html
the code is shown below:

```
<form class="login-box" name="loginForm" action="j_spring_security_check">
    <div class="login-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <div style="text-align:center"><img height="" width=""src="resources/images/demo.logo.000.jpg"></div>
                <h1>Login to <span><img height="" width=""src="resources/images/demo.logo.jpg"> <sup>TM</sup></span></h1>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="j_username" placeholder="User ID">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name='j_password' placeholder="Password">
                <input class="login" type="submit" value="Sign in"  formmethod="post"/>

                <div class="alert alert-error">  
                    <!-- Error Messages here -->     
                </div> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

now i am calling this page by interceptor but it gives the Warning as:

```
WARNING: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/WEB-INF/pages/home.html', method 'GET', parameters map[[empty]]
```

and finnalyy failed to render giving server error as

```
**HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.
VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.9.2.RELEASE/7.0.39.B.RELEASE**
```

but when i change my Login.html to login.jsp it works fine. 
following are my xml configurations

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
```

this is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
     <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                     /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
                     /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            </param-value>
            </context-param>
  </web-app>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:form-login login-page='/Login' default-target-url="/success" 
    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
    authentication-failure-url="/WEB-INF/pages/Login.jsp?error=true"/>
</security:http>
```

am i missing something ....??

Comment: Write interceptor code as well as web.xml code

Comment: @BhavikAmbani ok m posting it....

Comment: Why would you use .html files in the first place? If you want a static web site, Spring MVC is unnecessary. If you want it dynamic, than you needs JSPs (or any other dynamic view technology). Moreover, the whole poing of MVC is to go through a controller before going to the view. Accessing a view directly is thus not advised, and will never work if it's under WEB-INF.

Comment: @JBNizet ok a valid question ...
i have already tested this application with jsp... just for the sake of learning i am trying to access the html.

and also spring dosent bind us only to use jsps.

Comment: @MayurGupta, have you got your answer or I help you to find out ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to access an html file that's inside the WEB-INF directory. You can't access directly from the browser any resource that's inside WEB-INF. Put the html file into the web resources folder, but outside the WEB-INF and try again.

Comment: Thanks andres, what you have said is right, but only for learning purpose i have put it into web-inf, i know its a wrong practice, but the thing is i can access the .jsp page which is inside web-inf/pages/home.jsp, but the moment when i change the extension to home.html, it says 404 error.

Comment: In that case, seems like Spring Servlet is serving you the jsp  but not the html. Try changing your url-pattern of the mvc-dispatcher from / to /*

Answer (score 0):

If you are still intrested here is my solution

In web.xml add :-

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Authenticate</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Authenticate</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- SERVLET MAPPING FOR HTML -->

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Authenticate</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in Authenticate-servlet.xml add

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/WEB-INF/html/" />
```

Put yours html files in web-inf/html folder

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the entry in spring-security.xml ?

`authentication-failure-url="/WEB-INF/pages/Login.jsp?error=true"/>`

Shouldn't it...

```
authentication-failure-url="/WEB-INF/pages/Login.**html**?error=true"/>
```