# How to create view resolver for html in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-security

I have faced the problem when decided to create a web-app without JSPs, but using only HTML-pages which are under directory WEB-INF/pages.

I've made the view resolver:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Also I've imported all the resources in WEB-INF/pages:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="WEB-INF/pages/"/>
```

My controller have the following view:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@RequestMapping("/")
public String indexPage() {
    return "redirect:/index.html";
}
```

It works fine for mapping "/" (redirects to login page if not authenticated), but it is not secured for url "/index.html" due to importing of this page as static resource (but it will not work at all if not import it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Maybe, it will be interesting to anybody. The main servlet mapping that I had, had url-pattern: /** 
And that was my problem. As I understood the main servlet in someway intercepted viewResolver even if it had such configuration: `<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>`

When I make the configuration of servlet make as the next one:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

everything became ok.

Comment: The /app pattern (or something similar) helps us distinguish Dispatcher-
Servlet -served content from other types of content. But then we have an
implementation detail (specifically, the /app path) exposed in our URL s. That
leads to complicated URL rewriting tactics to hide the /app path. Spring in Action 3rd Edition page 192

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you want to do that ..... as putting pages under web-inf is a wrong practice.......

also the container cant access the static contents that are under web-inf folder. I have faced exactly same problem see [resource problem post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880307/unable-to-render-html-via-spring-security-while-jsp-works-fine).

what i have found from googling is you can access dynamic resources under web-inf folder but not the static. I have tried even regestring all the static contents (ie. css, js,html, etc) in xml at the first place but nothing worked. finally i moved my pages out and it worked with no configuration ....

so try moving the resources out of **web-inf** and under **webcontent**

tell me if you got some extras on this.

thanks.

Comment: Actually it's good practice to put files that just serve as views under WEB-INF, to hide them from direct access