# Actual role of WEB-INF in a java web application?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am creating a web application using Java, Spring, Hibernate and AngularJS.
but I am not clearly understand the role of `WEB-INF` directory. As per I know `WEB-INF` is a web directory where we keep our web configuration files. But I have seen some example in AngularJS app where js and html are put in `WEB-INF` folder and it is known that `WEB-INF` is not publicly accessed. So why do we put those files in `WEB-INF` and what actually mean of publicly accessed even when we response for a request html and js are visible to clients, and if we put in `WEB-INF` folder these files how to access those files.

I need some clarification on these few points before starting my app development.
Please anyone can help me regarding these issues.

Comment: In the case of accessing those file, you can refer to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21462018/379779

Answer (score 2):

As you said, we put configuration files into the `WEB-INF` folder. But there are cases when you use resource files (e.g. HTML templates) which are not sent to the client as-is, but usually some transformations or parameter substitution happens, which are usually handled by a `Servlet`.

It is ok to put such templates and resources to the `WEB-INF` folder because the files as are should not be visible/accessible to the clients but only the result of transformations/parameter substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

Resource files are frequently stored within WEB-INF because the Java servlet container will not directly serve those files. Instead, some Java controller code is being used to serve them indirectly. This is perfectly acceptable, but I would prefer a solution that serves static content from a different server and let the Java container handle dynamic code only. In a pinch, you might just add a reverse proxy and off-load static content handling that way.

Comment: Hi Elliott thank you for clarification. May i know more about reverse proxy and how to use with spring application Could you suggest me any websites where i can learn about this.

Comment: Many web proxies (Squid, Varnish) and web servers (Apache, IIS) can be setup to act as reverse proxies. This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Spring you can build your app without WEB-INF directory. For example: spring-boot + thymeleaf, it is possible put all html, css and js files to src/main/resources/static .. so WEB-INF directory is not necessary for all java web applications.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use WEB-INF at all.
Here's a simple [AngularJS example app](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/) (official Spring guide) on how to do this.

Now, like Elliot mentions, sometimes using proxies is a good idea (depending on the kind of traffic your application should support). You could also use a CDN, which is easier to set up and has no configuration requirement in your application.